# Glimpse of Background window shown when new Form is displayed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have main form.I invoke form2 from Mainform using `form2.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms["MainForm"]);`
then i invoke another form from form2

```
    this.Hide();
    form3.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms["MainForm"]);
    this.Dispose();
```

Everything works fine but when a form3 is displayed i get a glimpse of any window displayed in the background ie:If i had opened MS paint put it in the background the Paint window will come on top of my window for time less than a second and automatically go to the backgroud.
Why is this behavior.How can i correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `this.Hide()`, Form2 is hidden and another window needs to get focused. However, you opened Form2 with ShowDialog, which means Form2 is the only window that can get focused in your application. But since you hid Form2, Windows finds another window to focus (in this case MS Paint).

One suggestion for a solution could be to artificially give MainForm focus before hiding Form2:

```
Application.OpenForms["MainForm"].Activate();
this.Hide();
form3.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms["MainForm"]);
this.Dispose();
```

Perhaps a more beautiful solution would be to first open Form3, wait for it to be shown, and then hide Form2. To do this, put this code in Form2, when you want to show Form3:

```
form3.Shown += (_s, _e) => Application.OpenForms["Form2"].Hide();
form3.ShowDialog(Application.OpenForms["MainForm"]);
this.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are hiding your main window before showing the dialog so clearly you'll see another window for a split second, whichever is behind it.  What you are doing is also very risky, the odds are very high that your program loses the focus.  Both before and especially after showing the dialog, your program won't have a window that can receive the focus.  So the Windows window manager is forced to find another window to give the focus to, it will pick the window of another application.  Forcing yours in the background, making it disappear entirely if that window is big enough.

You'll need to take counter-measures.  You can hide your main window by delaying the Hide() call, the form's BeginInvoke() method is very handy for that.  And you'll need to ensure that your main window is visible again just before the dialog closes.  The dialog's FormClosing event is handy for that.  Albeit not 100% reliable if the dialog already wires the event instead of overriding OnFormClosing().

Thus:

```
    private void DisplayDialog_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        using (var dlg = new Form2()) {
            this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => this.Hide()));
            dlg.FormClosing += dlg_FormClosing;
            dlg.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
            dlg.Location = this.Location;
            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
                // etc..
            }
            dlg.FormClosing -= dlg_FormClosing;
        }
    }

    void dlg_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        if (!e.Cancel) this.Show();
    }
```

Or just don't hide your main window.  It isn't very useful, dialogs are annoying enough as-is, being modal and preventing any copy/paste.  Preventing the user from completely seeing the window just hides info that might be useful to the user.